# How to get bash arguments with leading pound-sign (octothorpe)

Tags: bash, parameters, arguments

I need to process an argument to a bash script that might or might not have a leading pound sign (octothorpe). The simplest example is:

```
echo #1234
```

which returns nothing

It might be because it processes the text as a command and assumes it is a comment.

$@, $*, etc. do not work. getopts does not seem to address this sort of thing.

Suggestions welcome

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is completely impossible, because the "argument" in question is parsed as a comment and *never passed to the command at all*.

Keep in mind that programs in C have the following calling convention for their `main` function:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
```

This means that programs are passed a list of individual, separate arguments, not a single string that isn't yet parsed. **The original string from which that vector of arguments was parsed is not given to the invoked program at all; often, no "original string" even exists.** Consequently, a program that was invoked has no way to "unring the bell" and go back from the parsed list of strings to the original string from which it was generated.

Consequently, if your script is invoked as an external command (as opposed to a shell function), the invocation of the shell that runs it by the operating system will go through [the `execve` syscall](https://linux.die.net/man/2/execve), which takes as its arguments (1) the file to execute; (2) the argument vector to pass it (which is to say, the aforementioned list of individual C strings); and (3) a list of environment variables. There is no argument for an unparsed shell command line, so no such content is available to the subprocess.

---

Train your users to use appropriate quoting. All of the below will have completely indistinguishable behavior, insofar as `yourscript` is concerned:

```
yourscript '#1234'  # single quotes prevent content from being parsed as shell syntax
yourscript ''#1234  # "#" only begins a comment at the front of a string
yourscript '#'1234  # note that shell quoting is character-by-character
yourscript \#1234   # ...so either quoting or escaping only that single character suffices.
```

...any of the above will pass an `argv` containing (in C syntax) `char[][]{ "yourscript", "#1234", NULL }`

Comment: Any idea _why_ a leading pound has this (presumably unintended) side-effect?

Comment: @RichardHaven, what do you mean, unintended? That's comment syntax. It's no more "unintended" than `/* something */` not being parsed as code in C, or `# something` not being parsed as code in Python, `// something` in C++, `<!-- something -->` in SGML-family languages, etc.

Comment: So it is treating the command-line as a single-line script, and the octothorpe is interpreted as a commend within that line.

I get it now. Thank you

Comment: @RichardHaven it is also possible to turn this behavior off for interactive shells with `shopt -u interactive_comments`.